# why i am not able to update env variable in node js

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I want to update my env variable in node js, but i am not able to update its env variable, i tried with `console.log(process.env.DB_HOST)` but still i am getting old value, here i have added my whole code, can anyone please look in to it, and help me to resolve this issue,

```
function exec_api() { 
    return new Promise(async function (resolve) {
        const execSync = require('child_process').exec;
        //let child_process_obj = execSync('DB_HOST='+process.env.UNITTEST_DB_HOST+' DB_DATABASE='+process.env.UNITTEST_DB_DATABASE+'  DB_USERNAME='+process.env.UNITTEST_DB_USERNAME+' DB_PASSWORD='+process.env.UNITTEST_DB_PASSWORD+'  PORT='+process.env.UNITTEST_SERVICE_PORT+' ./node_modules/.bin/nodemon main.js'); 
        await execSync('export DB_HOST=' + process.env.UNITTEST_DB_HOST);
        await execSync('export DB_DATABASE=' + process.env.UNITTEST_DB_DATABASE);
        await execSync('export DB_USERNAME=' + process.env.UNITTEST_DB_USERNAME);
        await execSync('export DB_PASSWORD=' + process.env.UNITTEST_DB_PASSWORD);
        await execSync('export PORT=' + process.env.UNITTEST_API_BACKEND_PORT);
        let child_process_obj = await execSync('node main.js');
        unittest_api_backend_process_id = child_process_obj.pid;
        resolve(true);
    });
}
```

Comment: `export` only works in a shell, but you are not using a shell to execute the commands. You should use the options parameter of `execSync` to set the env

Comment: can you give me example for it

Comment: why await for something synchronous ? what is this misuse of js ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## TLDR: Just change process.env

To change, add or delete environment variables, use `process.env`. The following is test code showing how this works:

In **main.js**:

```
console.log(process.env.DB_DATABASE);
```

In **exec.js**:

```
const execSync = require ('child_process').execSync;

process.env.DB_DATABASE = 'foo'; // this is ALL you need to do

console.log(execSync('node main.js').toString('utf8'));
```

With the two files above, if you run `node exec.js` you will see `foo` printed out in the console. This is printed from `main.js` which inherits the environment from `exec.js`.

So all you need to do in your code is:

```
function exec_api() { 
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        const exec = require('child_process').exec;

        // The following is node.js equivalent of bash "export":
        process.env.DB_HOST = process.env.UNITTEST_DB_HOST;
        process.env.DB_DATABASE = process.env.UNITTEST_DB_DATABASE;
        process.env.DB_USERNAME = process.env.UNITTEST_DB_USERNAME;
        process.env.DB_PASSWORD = process.env.UNITTEST_DB_PASSWORD;
        process.env.PORT = process.env.UNITTEST_SERVICE_PORT;

        let child_process_obj = exec('node main.js', {
            stdio: ['inherit', 'inherit', 'inherit']
        });
        
        unittest_api_backend_process_id = child_process_obj.pid;
        
        resolve(true);
    });
}
```

Note that if you want the promise to return when the `main.js` ends you need to do:

```
function exec_api() { 
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        const exec = require('child_process').exec;

        // The following is node.js equivalent of bash "export":
        process.env.DB_HOST = process.env.UNITTEST_DB_HOST;
        process.env.DB_DATABASE = process.env.UNITTEST_DB_DATABASE;
        process.env.DB_USERNAME = process.env.UNITTEST_DB_USERNAME;
        process.env.DB_PASSWORD = process.env.UNITTEST_DB_PASSWORD;
        process.env.PORT = process.env.UNITTEST_SERVICE_PORT;

        let child_process_obj = exec('node main.js', {
            stdio: ['inherit', 'inherit', 'inherit']
        });
        
        unittest_api_backend_process_id = child_process_obj.pid;
        
        child_process_obj.on('exit', () => resolve(true));

        // ^^^ Cannot use `await` as the API is not promise based
        //     but event based instead.
    });
}
```

---

## Long story: The full explanation of why `export` doesn't work

On unixen, environment variables, and indeed, the entire environment including current working directory, root directory (which can be changed via chroot) etc. are not features of shells. They are features of processes.

We may be familiar with the `export` syntax of some shells to set environment variables for child processes but that is the shell's syntax. It has nothing to do with environment variables themselves. C/C++ for example don't use `export` instead uses the [`setenv()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setenv.3.html) function do set environment variables (indeed, internally that's what bash/sh/ksh etc do when implementing `export`).

In node.js, the mechanism for reading and setting environment variables is via `process.env`.

#### Why asking a shell to do it don't work

This is not merely a node.js issue. It also won't work in bash:

In **exporter.sh**:

```
#! /bin/bash

export DB_DATABASE=$1
```

In **exec.sh**:

```
#! /bin/bash

./exporter.sh foo
echo $DB_DATABASE ;# does not print "foo"
```

This is a core security feature of unixen: **other users should not be allowed to mess with your process**. The way this policy is enforced in the case of the environment is that only a parent process can set the environment of the child process. A child process **is not allowed** to set the environment of the parent process. The assumption is that the child process **belongs** to the parent process so you should be allowed to do what you want to a program - but since the parent process (you) don't belong to the child process the child is not allowed to mess with the parent's environment.

That's why your attempt to use `export` doesn't work. It actually works (the variables are indeed created in the subshell) but is not allowed to change the environment of it's parent (the node.js process)

Answer (score 0):

When you use `export` in a terminal, it instructs the shell to set environment variables.

When you call `exec` from your code, you are not running such a shell, with the reason being that it would become a challenge to extract the output of every command.

This makes `export` an ignored command.

You can solve this by passing an [option object to `execSync`:](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options)

```
execSync('node main.js', {
    env: {
        DB_HOST: 'localhost',
         // More envs...
    }
}
```

Comment: i used that, but still when i used console.log(process.env.DB_DATABASE); i am getting old value

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `.env` file for storing ports; then here is something that worked for me.

1. Copy the content inside `.env` file
2. Now, delete the `.env` file.
3. Create new `.env` and paste the content in.
4. Now run (`npm install dotenv`)
5. Run your server